# From an architectural standpoint, should models in a rails application be able to set their own user association in an after_initialize function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, anti-patterns

Let us assume the following structure:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :set_defaults

  belongs_to :user

  ...

  private
    def :set_defaults
      self.user = SomeAuth.current_user
    end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions

  ...
end
```

Further, let us assume that `SomeAuth` is some black-box magic authentication scheme.
We can think of that as [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or [Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) (or insert your favorite ruby authentication solution here).

Under those assumptions, is it an anti-pattern to have a `Question` set its own `user` attribute after initialization (for all intents and purposes, after `Question.new` is called, i.e. in an `after_initialize` macro)?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't want to classify it as a good or bad pattern in absolute terms.

If your system is only one RoR application, then it seems like a good pattern. You use a mechanism provided by a framework thus not creating extra code and keeping it pretty simple. Your domain object is tied to your auth scheme, but in this simple context it may be  beneficial.

If your system is collection of many distinct applications, and you want to reuse a domain model between them, then you might want to divorce your domain and auth concepts. Some subsystems may not care about auth concerns (like batch processing of a certain kind). In this context an explicit relationship between domain and auth (and the way it gets loaded) might be an anti-pattern.

Comment: I have an enterprise background. There, systems are rarely silos. Different problem domains often share objects. Naturally, this idea of tying a domain object to the authentication scheme of a specific domain worried me a bit. I suppose that I can couple the object to the auth scheme for now, and worry about abstractions and generalizations later...